# Multiprocessing pool starmap gives OS error: too many files open

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

So I am running this script which uses multiprocessing pool to run a function in parallel. My code was earlier of the form :

```
with mp.pool(n_workers) as pool:
    for i in range(some_iterations):
        for ele in some_list:
            soln = pool.starmap(some_function, some_arguments)
            add_soln_to_json(soln)
```

but i made a change where i have to check some condition and run the starmap an extra time. so my code becomes :

```
with mp.pool(n_workers) as pool:
    for i in range(some_iterations):
        for ele in some_list:
            soln = pool.starmap(some_function, some_arguments)
            add_soln_to_json(soln)
            if(some_condition):
                soln = pool.starmap(some_function, some_arguments)
                add_soln_to_json(soln)
```

my program now keeps on giving me OS error : too many open files. I do not get why adding an extra step which runs the same function but on slightly differing arguments causes this error. Also since everything is under context manager there is no problem of not closing processes. Or should i replace this with manually opening and closing multiprocessing pool?

This is the error traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/share/pkg.7/python3/3.7.7/install/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 149, in _serve
    send(conn, destination_pid)
  File "/share/pkg.7/python3/3.7.7/install/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 50, in send
    reduction.send_handle(conn, new_fd, pid)
  File "/share/pkg.7/python3/3.7.7/install/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 179, in send_handle
    with socket.fromfd(conn.fileno(), socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
  File "/share/pkg.7/python3/3.7.7/install/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 463, in fromfd
    nfd = dup(fd)
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

Comment: Check and possibly increase the allowed open files of the OS. Also make sure not to open too many files/sockets and close them if not needed anymore.

Comment: hey @KlausD. do you know how can i check the number of open files/sockets.